# Type 'Observable<Response> ' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>'

Tags: javascript, angular, download, observable

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I am using Angular 8 and trying to create a downloadable link for blob file.
In Visual Studio code, I am getting the following error in file.service.ts:
Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable>'. Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpResponse':body, clone ts

I am getting the following error in my service code:

```
                ERROR in src/app/file.service.ts:15:3 - error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Response>
            ' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>'.
              Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpResponse<Bl
            ob>': body, clone

            15      return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/#/LabViewerRTF', { responseT
            ype: ResponseContentType.Blob });
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is my file.service.ts file:

```
                import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
            import {HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
            import {Http, ResponseContentType} from '@angular/http';

            import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

            @Injectable({
              providedIn: 'root'
            })
            export class FileService {

              constructor(private http: Http) {}

              downloadFile(): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>{       
                    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/#/LabViewerRTF', { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });
               }
            }
```

Here is my app.component.ts:

```
                import { Component } from '@angular/core';
            import { FileService } from './file.service';
            import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


            @Component({
              selector: 'app-root',
              templateUrl: './app.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
            })
            export class AppComponent {
              itle = 'Angular File Download';

              constructor(private fileService: FileService) {}

              download() {
                this.fileService.downloadFile().subscribe(response => {
                        //let blob:any = new Blob([response.blob()], { type: 'text/json; charset=utf-8' });
                        //const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        //window.open(url);
                        window.location.href = response.url;
                        //fileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'employees.json');
                    }), error => console.log('Error downloading the file'),
                     () => console.info('File downloaded successfully');
              }
            }
```

Here is my app.component.html:

```
                <div style="text-align:center">
              <h1>
                Welcome to {{ title }}
              </h1>
            </div>
            <h2>Click below link to get employee data</h2>
            <div>
                <h3>
                    Using Link <br/>
                    <a href="#" (click)="download()">Download Employee Data</a>
                </h3>

                <h3>Using Button</h3>
                <input type="button" (click)="download()" value="Download Employee Data"/>
            </div>


            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: just try Observable<Blob>

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is your return type. It's not

`Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>`

it's (if memory serves me) just supposed to be

```
Observable<Blob>
```

It's actually telling you this: you can not assign:

```
Observable<Response>
```

To what you're trying to assign it to. And since we know the response you're looking for is "Blob" (which I imagine is compatible with Response via interface, subtype, etc), `Observable<Blob>` would seem right.

I looked in a couple of places after posting this, seems memory did serve me...this time.

If that's not it, you could just "any" it:

```
Observable<any>
```

Or go with what it's telling you:

```
Observable<Response>
```

Debugger/console.log it, see what you get, and then adjust the typing accordingly.